# How to get openerTabId from inactive tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I loaded a tab with inactive, and this tab have script open popup when few seconds.

when i try to catch `openerTabId` from popup by `chrome.tabs.onCreated` . it allway show `tabId` of active tab.

and how to get `openerTabId` from real tab (inactive tab)

In background script:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener((tab)=>{
    console.log("tabid: "+tab.id+ "was created");
    if(typeof tab.openerTabId != "undefined") console.log("this tab open from tab: "+tab.openerTabId);
});

chrome.tabs.create({url:'http://localhost/test/test.html',active:false});
```

in `test.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.open("https://google.com.vn");
    },3000);
</script>
```

and the result console:

```
tabid: 359was created
tabid: 361was created
this tab open from tab: 291
```

and i sure tabId 291 is active tab.

Comment: Show please your code.

Comment: @Deliaz i created my code

Comment: It's possible `window.open` doesn't set the real openerTabId.

Comment: @wOxxOm but, if this tab active, it give real openerTabId

Comment: You may want to see this [thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/iL5AfvHSXJU) and see if it will help you.